# Is potential energy and "work done" the same thing?

Tags: newtonian-mechanics, energy, work, potential-energy

Is [potential energy](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Potential_energy) and "[work](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Work_%28physics%29) done" the same thing?

If they are not one and the same thing then why is potential energy always associated with "work done"?

Could you explain me with some examples?

Comment: It's analogous to the question: Is the money in the wallet the same thing as the money spent for food and other expenses? What do you think the answer is? They're quantities of the same "kind", with the same units, but the precise values are different because they're different "accounts".

Answer (score 9):

Potential energy and work done are the same thing as much as kinetic energy and work done are the same thing. Potential energy is a state of the system, a way of storing energy as of virtue of its configuration or motion, while work done in most cases is a way of chaning this energy from one body to another.

For ex when a body is dropped from a height, its gravitational energy a virtue of its configuration with respect to the earth is converted into kinetic energy a virtue of its motion, due to the work done by gravity in bringing it down.

Answer (score 4):

Suppose you drive your car to the store and back. Your car started and finished in the same place (on your drive) so its potential energy hasn't changed but during the trip the car engine did a lot of work. This is an example where the work done is not equal to the change in potential energy.

Generally speaking in physics we are interested in [conservative forces](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Conservative_force), and one of the definitions of a conservative force is that the work done is equal to the change in potential energy. This normally means energy neither leaves or enters the system we are considering. The reason the example I gave of the car journey is non-conservative is that friction and drag causes energy to leave the system (as heat). In principle if your car had no friction or drag then it would use no energy going to the store unless the store was at a different height. If the store was at a different height then any energy used going to the store would be recovered on the way back.

Comment: But according to the equation $W=$∆$U=$∆$KE+W_{NC}$ (Where $W_{NC}$ is the work done by the engine in a nonconservative fashion), since ∆$KE$ is zero, the work done by the engine $W=$∆$U=W_{NC}$, correct?

Answer (score 2):

You will have to spend some energy to do work. This is called the work done. This energy that you spent is stored inside the body on which you do work as the potential energy. That is why you always see work done equated to potential energy.

Comment: $\LaTeX \space \LaTeX $

Answer (score 1):

Potential energy is a concept of the energy that results from the object's position; as a concept it refers to the work you have to do to move the object from $U=0\,.$

To any another point at $U= 0$ we call this point the reference point and it's like how to choose the origin of the coordinate system.

Answer (score 0):

Potential energy is the energy possessed by a body by virtue of its position or configuration . And energy is the capacity of doing work since power is work divided by time therefore change in potential energy divided by time is equal to the power of the object.

Answer (score -5):

Well PE and Work can be the same thing if seen mathematially,
m = 100kg
d =2.2 m

work = F * d
     = 100(9.8)(2.2)
     = 21560.0 J

PE = mgh
   = F * h
   = 980 * 2.2
   = 2156.0 J

Comment: Why are $h$ and $d$ the same here?

Comment: Taking certain constants and proving the lack of a contradiction isn't a convincing way to prove this: it can't be generalized at all.